# Combining tikz (math library) with mercatormap

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to combine the tikzlibrary math with the package mercatormap but this doesn't work anymore. Below is code that works fine (in reality it makes sense to write functions. It is part of an animation.) but when you un-comment the mercatormap, it just hangs up pdflatex.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

%\usepackage{mercatormap}
%\mrcactivatescript% activates Python script

\begin{document}
    \tikzmath{
        real \x, \y, \z, \xr, \yr, \zr, \xp, \yp, \zp;
        \x=0;
        \y=0.25;
        \z=0.25;
        function xrot(\ix,\iy,\iz,\ang){
            return cos(\ang)*\ix+sin(\ang)*\iy;
        }; 
        function yrot(\ix,\iy,\iz,\ang){
            return -sin(\ang)*\ix+cos(\ang)*\iy;
        }; 
        function zrot(\ix,\iy,\iz,\ang){
            return \iz;
        }; 
        function xproj(\ix,\iy,\iz){
            return -3;
        };
        function yproj(\ix,\iy,\iz){
            return -4/(\ix-1)*\iy;
        };
        function zproj(\ix,\iy,\iz){
            return -4/(\ix-1)*\iz;
        };
    }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    
        \tikzmath{  
            \xr = xrot(\x,\y,\z,6);
            \yr = yrot(\x,\y,\z,6);
            \zr = zrot(\x,\y,\z,6);
            \xp = xproj(\xr,\yr,\zr);
            \yp = yproj(\xr,\yr,\zr);
            \zp = zproj(\xr,\yr,\zr);           
        }
        \draw (-2,-2) -- (-2,2) -- (2,2) -- (2,-2) -- cycle;
        \node (pppp) at (\yp,\zp) {};
        \filldraw [blue] (pppp) circle [radius=1.5pt];
        \node (t) at (3.11,0) {}; 
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using mercatormap elsewhere. Any ideas?

Comment: use a  different name for `\ang`, e.g. `\angx`. mercatormap loads siunitx and that defines \ang too.

Comment: OK, that solves the problem. It works now. I never could have found that myself.

Comment: How do I mark this problem now as answered? I did something wrong last time and I got some aggressive remarks because of my mistake.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Would you like to add an answer, so that Michel can mark it as accepted?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it was answered in the comments.